# TypeScript AngularJS inject one angular module into another angular module

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Here is my one main angular module with constant defined on it.

```
/// <reference path="../../../thirdparty/angular/angular.d.ts"/>
var FeatureFlagsValues: ng.IModule = angular.module('feature-flags.values', []);
 FeatureFlagsValues.constant('FeatureFlagValues', {});
 FeatureFlagsValues.run(['$q', '$http', 'FeatureFlagValues', function (_q:ng.IQService, _http: ng.IHttpService, FeatureFlagValues: any) {
let deferred = _q.defer();
let uri = "/api/v1/features/user";

_http.get(uri)
    .success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
        deferred.reject({data,status});
    });

deferred.promise.then((results: any) => {
    angular.forEach(results.EnabledFlags, function (key) {
        FeatureFlagValues[key] = true;
    });
});
deferred = _q.defer();
uri = '/api/v1/features/user?defaults=true';

_http.get(uri)
    .success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
        deferred.reject({ data, status });
    });
deferred.promise.then((defaultResults: any) => {
    angular.forEach(defaultResults.EnabledFlags, function (key) {
        FeatureFlagValues[key] = true;
    });
 });

}]);
```

Here is my another angular module in which I want use the constant defined in previous module, I am not sure how can i do that. I did research couldn't find any good example.

```
 // <reference path="./FeatureFlags.values.ts"/>
 import {Endpoints as endpoints} from '../../endpointsTsModule';
 import {FeatureFalgs as FF}  from './FeatureFlags.service.SettingStore';

 export module FeatureFlags.service {
 export class FeatureFlagsService {
 static $inject: string[] = ["$q", "$http", "feature-flags.values","FeatureFlagsSettingStore"];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the 'FeatureFlagValues' constant you need to make the 'feature-flags.values' module a dependency of the "another angular module" you are referring to. Like so:

```
angular.module('another', ['feature-flags.values']);
```

Then you can access it in your service by just injecting it like so:

```
 export class FeatureFlagsService {
     static $inject: string[] = ["$q", "$http", "FeatureFlagValues","FeatureFlagsSettingStore"];
   }
```